# Own messages flagged in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, flags

When your own message is flagged in chat, then that annoying blue circle comes up- but you can't just click "invalid" to get rid of it, because you can't counter-flag your own messages. Since I'm not allowed to have an opinion on the flagging of my own message, please don't show the *extremely* annoying blue circle.

Comment: So you want us to hide the fact that your message is flagged fom you?

Comment: @balpha well you hide the fact that our posts and comments are being flagged, don't you ;)

Comment: @balpha: There's already a notification *on* the message. I don't need the extremely annoying blue circle which is screaming "Please do something about this flag!oneone!!111!one" when I can't actually *do* anything.